# Can you help me change the red square in this game to an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw a game online with a source code and I wanted to change the red square to an image of Flappy bird because the game looks just like it. Can you help me with changing the red square to an image?

HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you provide codes to change the controls and backgrounds? I want to make a game on my own based on this and learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Define an image in your HTML and hide it with CSS:

```
<img id="sourceImg" src="http://placebacon.net/40/40" style="display: none;">
```

(2) Create a new "image" type in your `component` function:

```
if (this.type == "text") {
    ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
} else if(this.type == "image") {
    var image = document.getElementById('sourceImg');
    ctx.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y)
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

(3) Use this new type when creating your game piece:

```
myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, null, 10, 120, "image");
```

(4) ??

(5) Profit!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<img id="sourceImg" src="http://placebacon.net/40/40" style="display: none;">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, null, 10, 120, "image");
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else if(this.type == "image") {
            var image = document.getElementById('sourceImg');
            ctx.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y)
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the backfound color change the line

background-color: #f1f1f1;

To draw image use [drawImage()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

You can add a else if statement on the compponent function, taht creates the square.

```
else if (this.type == "img") {
    var img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src=src;
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Then to chanche controls you have to adda othe buttons and modificate the way the affect the movement, in the newPos() function
Inthe is like this:

```
this.newPos = function() {
    //this line increases gravity value
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    //This line is movinh foward
    this.x += this.speedX;
    //This line makes the object falls
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;

    this.hitBottom();
}
```

I have modificated the controls to up and down buttons in the exemple.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: rgb(255,123,11);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    <script>

    var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacles = [];
    var myScore;

    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120, "img", "https://www.spreadshirt.ca/image-server/v1/mp/designs/12679277,width=178,height=178/red-flappy-bird.png");
        myGamePiece.gravity = 0;
        myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type, src) {
        this.type = type;
        this.src = src;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.gravity = 0;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            } else if (this.type == "img") {
                var img=document.createElement('img');
                img.src=src;
                
                ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
            this.hitBottom();
        }
        this.hitBottom = function() {
            var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            if (this.y > rockbottom) {
                this.y = rockbottom;
                this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            }
        }
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                return;
            } 
        }
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight = 20;
            maxHeight = 200;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap = 50;
            maxGap = 200;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }

    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }

    function accelerate(n) {
        myGamePiece.gravity = n;
    }

    function move(n) {
        myGamePiece.gravity = n;   
    }

    function stopMove() {
        myGamePiece.gravity = 0;      
    }

    </script>
    <br>
    <!--<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>-->
    <button onmousedown="move(-0.2)" onmouseup="stopMove()">^</button>
    <button onmousedown="move(0.2)" onmouseup="stopMove()">v</button>
    <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
    <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```